# How to put an image as watermark in TextField using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Click on the following link,
[TextBox with search Image on Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqG6X.png)

i want the text box exactly the sameway with watermark in it.
I tried multiple ways,but nothing worked

Content from my .xhtml file

```
<h:inputText id="bundelId" styleClass="icon2"  value="">

<p:watermark value="Enter Bundel Id" for="bundelId"     styleClass="icon2"></p:watermark> 
                                  </h:inputText>
```

My css contains following classes

```
.icon2 {


background: url(search.gif) no-repeat 4px 4px;
padding:4px  4px 2px 20px;
height:10px;
margin: 0;

}

.icon3 {



float: right;
background: url(search.gif) no-repeat left bottom;
border: 0;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0;

}
```

I have tried with both jsf and primefaces tags together with css classes mentioned above.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using FontAwesome you could try:

```
<p:watermark value="&#xF002; Enter Bundel Id" for="bundelId" />

<h:inputText id="bundelId" value="" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
```

`&#xF002;` being the unicode for  icon-search.
 https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: this actually works :D in my case I had to remove `Arial` from the font-family otherwise it would write `fl` instead of the icon